# Is this why im getting a typeerror?

Tags: javascript, typeerror

```
var colourArray = [
  "rgb(248, 155, 165)",
  "rgb(248, 160, 170)",
  "rgb(248, 160, 180)",
  "rgb(248, 175, 195)",
  "rgb(249, 184, 195)",
  "rgb(248, 195, 215)",
  "rgb(248, 205, 235)",
  "rgb(248, 225, 225)",
  "rgb(248, 116, 138)",
];

changingColorsArray = [...colourArray];



function arrayRotate(arr, reverse) {
  if (reverse) arr.unshift(arr.pop());
  else arr.push(arr.shift());
  return arr;
}




var banner = document.getElementsByClassName('banner')[0].innerHTML

var bannerArray = banner.split('')



function applyColors(letters, colorArr) {
  for (let i = 0; i < letters.length; i++) {
    letters[i].style.color = colorArr[i];
  }
}


myInterval = setInterval(() => {

  arrayRotate(changingColorsArray, true);

  applyColors(bannerArray, changingColorsArray);
}, 1600);
```

My html

```
<div class="banner">Funny Klock</div>
```

so far ive gathered that `letters[i]` is accessing an index of an array

```
letters[i].style.color = colorArr[i];
```

hence cannot set the property of that item, unlike a span, div or class,  PLEASE tell me if  im right.

Plus, how would you access the color property and loop through the innerhtml to give each letter a different color

Comment: PLease [edit] your question to include a [mre].

Comment: You can't style letters being part of a string. But you can style html elements.. so it means you should embed each one of those letters in a standalone span. Unless you come up with a better solution that I can't think of

Comment: there's an old jQuery plugin called "lettering.js" that facilitates stuff like this.

Comment: Please use `Array.from(banner)`, not `banner.split("")`. See [How do I split a string into an array of characters?](/a/38901550/4642212).

Comment: so am i right in assuming the type error is due to trying to set a property on an array item?

Comment: You don't just have to 'assume', you can always debug. [Try it](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/javascript/)

Comment: you were accessing to the `style` property of a string value (one character of a string is still a string) .. there's not such property. It doesn't matter if it was an element of an array. It was a string. You cannot style a string.. the style property belongs to HTMLElement so you had to reimagine your strategy. Something I attempted in my answer

Comment: ...and FYI `const value = 'test'; console.log(typeof value); //->string console.log(typeof value[0]); //->string`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example using the strategy I suggested in the comments.

I mostly focused on the *"letterize"* approach. So that there's a function `letterizeElementContent` that will change the content of each `.banner` element, creating a span embedding each letter of its original content.

Later, the function passed to `setInterval`, will just apply the desired style to each of the `.letter` span contained in the `.banner` elements, following the colour map specified in the colourArray that will be rotating at each interval passed.

```js
const colourArray = [
  "rgb(248, 155, 165)",
  "rgb(248, 160, 170)",
  "rgb(248, 160, 180)",
  "rgb(248, 175, 195)",
  "rgb(249, 184, 195)",
  "rgb(248, 195, 215)",
  "rgb(248, 205, 235)",
  "rgb(248, 225, 225)",
  "rgb(248, 116, 138)",
]; 

//split the letters and embed them in spans for each .banner element
document.querySelectorAll('.banner')
  .forEach(banner => {
    letterizeElementContent(banner);
  });

//change color schema every 1.6s
let changingColorsArray = [...colourArray];
myInterval = setInterval(() => {
  //rotates the colors array  
  arrayRotate(changingColorsArray, true);
  //for each element having the banner class
  document.querySelectorAll('.banner')
    .forEach(banner => {
      //apply colors from changingColorsArray for each letter
      applyColors(banner, changingColorsArray);
    });
    
  }, 1600);

//converts the text content of the given element in html spans wrapping each letter
function letterizeElementContent(element){
  
  const textContent = element.textContent;
  
  element.dataset.original = textContent;  
  element.innerText = '';
  
  [...textContent].forEach( letter => {  
    const letterSpan = document.createElement('span');
    letterSpan.classList.add('letter');
    letterSpan.innerText = letter;
    element.append(letterSpan);  
  });  
}

function applyColors(element, colors){
  let i = 0;
  element
    .querySelectorAll('.letter')
      .forEach(letter => {
        if(++i > colors.length)
          i=1;        
        const color = colors[i-1];        
        //console.log(i, color);
        letter.style.color = color;
      });
}

function arrayRotate(arr, reverse) {
  if (reverse) arr.unshift(arr.pop());
  else arr.push(arr.shift());
  return arr;
}
```

```css
.letter{
  /*border: solid 1px;*/
}

.banner{
  font-size: 3rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="banner">Funny Klock</div>


<div class="banner">Second Clock</div>
```

Comment: cool, i thought i may have to use spans on each letter